# Is Boostrap compatible with Struts 2?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, struts2, struts2-bootstrap-plugin

I am using Bootstrap for my UI development. When I use Struts 2 tags for `textfield` in it, the complete page alignment is destroyed. When I replace the `s:` (Struts 2 tags) tags with normal tags, it is working fine.

Do I need to include any extra jar?

Answer (score 2):

Struts 2 uses themes while rendering output of the JSP page. You can read more about themes in [Struts 2 Themes](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/themes.html). To change a default theme put this in the `struts.xml`

```
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple"/>
```

Comment: Hi, I have added <constant name> tag to my struts.xml. I found this is the same like adding theme="simple" in each <s:textfield> tags, and the issue with display has gone, but I used xml based validations(Action class name-validations.xml) in my application. If i include 'simple' theme in application those validations are not read. And I observed after removing this theme 'simple', validations are done but page alignment has gone.

Comment: Hi,
I think it has almost done but, <s:textfield> tags which all I am giving inside <div class="col-xs-4"> is not comes under proper alignment.

Below structure I used in my JSPs.

<div class="container">
    <s:form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                  <s:textfield id="abc" label = "ABC"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                  <s:textfield id="def" label = "DEF"/>
            </div>
         </
     </
</

Answer (score 2):

> **Solution n.1**:

Use the `simple` theme and write the Bootstrap-compliant HTML on your own:

```
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
```

> **Solution n.2**:

Use the [Struts2 Boostrap plugin](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-bootstrap/) ([showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-bootstrap-showcase/index.action)) and the `bootstrap` theme and let it automatically generate the Bootstrap-compliant HTML from Struts tags:

```
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="bootstrap" />
```